# NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'mat-error'

Tags: angular

I have structured my shared components to have its own module.

I am trying to create a template driven form.
I believe I have done everything right but somehow I cannot see the error message when required field is not filled. And an error message shows in the console.

```html
<!-- login.component.html -->
<mat-card>
    <form #form="ngForm" (submit)="onSubmit(form)">
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="email" matInput name="email" ngModel #email="ngModel" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="true">email required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
        <mat-form-field>
            <input type="password" matInput name="password" ngModel #password="ngModel" required>
            <mat-error *ngIf="password.invalid">password required</mat-error>
        </mat-form-field>
        <button mat-button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</mat-card>
```

```js
// shared.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from 'src/app/added.modules/angular.material/angular.material.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from 'src/app/app-routing.module';
import { JoinComponent } from './auth/join/join.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './auth/login/login.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    JoinComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
  ],
  imports: [ AngularMaterialModule, AppRoutingModule, FormsModule],
  exports: [HeaderComponent, JoinComponent, LoginComponent, ErrorComponent],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

[image]

The problem was that I was missing BrowserModule in my shared module.

```js
// shared.module.ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

// this one was needed
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
// this one was needed

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AngularMaterialModule } from 'src/app/added.modules/angular.material/angular.material.module';
import { AppRoutingModule } from 'src/app/app-routing.module';
import { JoinComponent } from './auth/join/join.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './auth/login/login.component';
import { ErrorComponent } from './error/error.component';
import { HeaderComponent } from './header/header.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    JoinComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    ErrorComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AngularMaterialModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
  ],
  exports: [HeaderComponent, JoinComponent, LoginComponent, ErrorComponent],
})
export class SharedModule {}
```

Now it is working good!
[image]

Comment: aren't you missing the `CommonModule` ?

Comment: *Now it is working good*....so what's the problem?

Comment: For future reference. if you don't like it why bother leaving a comment?

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler Thanks for the comment. I had not thought about that as the problem was solved before I got there.

Answer (score 0):

BrowserModule or BrowserAnimationModule should only be imported once in the root module, app.module.ts.

Any other module (shared/core/business) should import CommonModule which offers structural directives such as ngFor and ngIf, attribute directives such as ngStyle ngClass.

Also in your shared module, if you are reusing it in any other module, you can import and export in shared the CommonModule so that you won’t have to explicitly import it in any other modules which are using Shared.

Be aware when working with many modules and all of those modules are using HttpClient, import HttpModule only in 1 core, as if you will define interceptors and you would import in some other module the HttpModule, those interceptors will be overwritten.

Comment: Thanks, Adrian! your comment gives me a more profound understanding of better handling or preventing the error in the future!